# How to get last 12 month of data with New York Timezone in mysql?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have a table `transaction`, which have `created` date in UTC, I want to get all the data with New York Timezone in mysql, can anyone please help me for that?
here is my query for that

```
$user_db = Common_Users_Helper::get_user_db_conn($this->session->userdata('id'), '');
$user_db->select('amount, created,MONTHNAME(created) as month, sponsorion_fees, processor_fees, amount_after_fees, SUM(amount_after_fees) as total');
$user_db->from('transaction');
$user_db->order_by('id', 'ASC');
$user_db->group_by('month');
$user_db->where('record_owner_user_id', $id);
$user_db->where('is_one_time_purchase', 'Y');
$user_db->where('created <= utc_timestamp() and created >= Date_add(utc_timestamp(),interval - 12 month)');
$query = $user_db->get();
//echo $user_db->last_query(); die;
$result = $query->result_array();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get current time in New York by setting timezone in PHP as,

```
 date_default_timezone_set('America/New_York');
 $currentdatetime = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

Then in your query, replace `utc_timestamp()` with `$currentdatetime`

```
$user_db->where('created <= "'.$currentdatetime.'" and created >= Date_add("'.$currentdatetime.'",interval - 12 month)');
```

To display created time in New York timezone,

```
// Set based timezone as UTC
date_default_timezone_set('UTC');
$date = '2018-11-15 10:56:00';
$timestamp = strtotime($date); // create timestamp

date_default_timezone_set('America/New_York'); // Set required timezone
echo $nydate = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $timestamp); // Convert timestamp in NY
```

Comment: Do we need to convert created column as New york time ?

Comment: If you want to show it somewhere in the UI, then yes.

Comment: Thanks for your help